# Error of Richardson Extrapolation with composite midpoint rule

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, extrapolation

My goal is to find an (exact) error expression for Richardson extrapolation applied to the composite midpoint rule. I know that the error for this rule is $$\displaystyle\frac{(b-a)h^2}{6}f^{''}(\xi)$$ and the Richardson extrapolation in this case would be equal to  $$I_h^R(f)(x=\displaystyle\frac{I_h(f)(x)-4I_{h/2}(f)(x)+3f(x)}{-3}$$ where $I_h$ is the composite midpoint rule with step $h$ and so on. When substituting looking for the error, I reach an expression of the form $$\displaystyle\frac{(b-a)h^2(f^{''}(\xi)-f^{''}(\xi'))}{-18}$$ I thought of applying MVT, but it's unknown if those two points are less than a distance of $h$ apart.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need at least one more term in the error expansion of the original method. Then perhaps start with just one segment.

Comment: I don't get it. The exact formula for the error is the one given.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But here you need more structure in the error expansion to see how the leading error terms cancel. Taylor polynomials of varying degrees have all exact error terms, what degree is needed depends on the application.